# Inserir um select com mais de um resultado

Tags: oracle

preciso executar o seguinte comando em um DB ORACLE:
Elaborar um select que retorna mais de um resultado e o resultado desse select preciso usar para fazer um insert em várias linhas.

Ex: meu select retornou 2 resultados: A e B, esse resultados devem ser inseridos em 2 linhas:

```
A
B
```

como posso fazer isso?
Segue código elaborado:

```
DECLARE 
cursor insere is 
select campo_valor_tarefa.ds_valor from campo_valor_tarefa
inner join fluxo
on campo_valor_tarefa.cd_fluxo = fluxo.cd_fluxo
where campo_valor_tarefa.cd_tarefa = 2 and campo_valor_tarefa.cd_campo = 10 and fluxo.cd_processo = 180 and campo_valor_tarefa.cd_fluxo <344;

linha insere%rowtype;
BEGIN

OPEN insere;
loop
FETCH insere into linha;
exit when insere%notfound;

UPDATE campo_valor_tarefa set ds_valor = (
SELECT ds_valor FROM CAMPO_VALOR_TAREFA WHERE cd_campo = 10 AND cd_tarefa=2 AND cd_fluxo = 341
)
where cd_campo = 126 and cd_tarefa = 6 and cd_fluxo = 344;
end loop;
close insere;
end;
```

Se eu executar o select no inicio do código ele retorna 2 resultados e na hora de executar o insert/update ele insere somente 1 resultado em todas as linhas.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer isso utilizando um loop, que para cada "linha" seja feito um insert, veja esse exemplo que faz um select e para cada linha faz um insert separado:

```
create or replace procedure P_EXEMPLO  is
      Cursor CONSULTA IS
        select COLUNA1, COLUNA2 from TABELA order by 1, 2;
        LINHA CONSULTA %ROWTYPE;
      begin
        DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
        OPEN   CONSULTA;
        LOOP
        FETCH  CONSULTA  INTO   LINHA;
        EXIT   WHEN   CONSULTA%NOTFOUND;

          BEGIN 
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Incluindo novos registros');
              INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(LINHA.COLUNA1, LINHA.COLUNA2);
          END;

        END LOOP; 
        COMMIT;
        CLOSE  CONSULTA;
      end P_EXEMPLO;
```

Comment: postei o codigo que fiz com base em seu exemplo. Ele faz o select de 3 informações, porem adiciona apenas uma em todas as linhas.